# How to use Mac microphone for a phone call on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, audio, microphone, phone.app

My iPhone is plugged into my Mac. I have a nice USB mic on the Mac I'd like to use for calls. I'm used to using Rogue Amoeba's software (e.g. Airfoil) so I know it's possible to pipe the audio around. How do I use the Mac's USB mic for my iPhone?

Comment: What did you already try?  What errors did you get?

Comment: i tried asking on stack exchange and erroneously had to answer this comment

Comment: What do you mean 'erroneously had to answer this comment'?

Comment: it was the error i encountered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the FaceTime app on your Mac to place calls via your iPhone.

To set this up it should be as simple as signing into the same Wi-Fi on both devices (Mac & iPhone) and the same FaceTime account on both devices.

From here you can make calls by just typing the number into this box in FaceTime:

[image]

As for using the microphone, you can configure which devices to use for speaker, microphone and webcam in the "Video" menu...

[image]

Finally once you've linked this all up inbound calls should show up as a notification you can answer on the Mac. If you prefer to answer on iPhone you can do this and then on the iPhone call app you can click the "Audio" option to route the call to your Mac where the FaceTime app will take over...

[image]

EDIT: Evidence that FaceTime can make calls from the Mac via an iPhone:

[image]

Comment: thats super cool and everything but i need to be able to *receive* regular cellphone calls not using the FaceTime app.  How do I configure the Mac/iPhone such that the iPhone recognizes an external mic in the Mac?

Comment: This is for regular external calls. It routes the audio data from the microphone to your iPhone and out to the cellular network. The FaceTime app is just he software that enables this. It isn’t just for making video chat calls and voice data calls. It can also make real telephone calls.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the option you get when you try to make a call from Mac, it says "Call Using iPhone"

Comment: sickness bruh thx